# How to hide the Keyboard on <select> Tag (Mobile device)

Tags: jquery, html, iphone

Is there a way to hide the iphone keyboard on a normal select tag?

Example:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I just want the "standard" dropdown on the iphone and not the keyboard comming up with the options.

Thanks :-)

Comment: why do you want to modify the default behavior of a select on mobile, what will your user do if they see a dropdown but doesn't work like a normal mobile dropdown?

Comment: here is the problem:
i use the pickadate.js and when the calender opens in a layer the page jumps to the bottom, after selecting a date - and than i have to scroll all the way back up.

Comment: by adding : at the end of your comment  i can only tell that you are missing (-) the dudster